# Django ORM join without explicit Foriegn Key

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.5

I have two sample models:

```
class Property(models.Model):
  address = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
  latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
class Business(models.Model):
  address = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

Without a fk relationship in the models how can I query a Business and get it's name, latitude, and longitude? Currently I am running two queries and iterating over them to make a single dictionary.

I know this is possible with raw but Im hoping it can be done through the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I could get without PURELY going with raw:

```
businesses = Business.objects.extra(
  select={
    "lat": "SELECT latitude FROM property_table WHERE  business_table.address = property_table.address",
    "lon": "SELECT longitude FROM property_table WHERE business_table.address = property_table.address"
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that, is to join by `address` attribute (common attribute in both Models). Assuming that they are the same and an address  is related to one business only.

```
business = Business.objects.get(pk=your_businness_id)

property = Property.objects.filter(address=business.address)[0] # be careful here, because may be you have d
```

**NOTES:**

1 - If my previous assuption is wrong, you need add a ForeignKey.

2 - If you want to join by other attribute, you can't, you will need add a `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score -1):

The ORM delegates the joining and retrieving of related data to the database. As the docs say, Django "[tak[es] care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)". If you don't specify a foreign key in your model, the database doesn't have any notion of linking the two tables. The Django ORM won't be able to span the relationship between the two tables without you doing extra work — either in raw SQL or by making multiple ORM queries that you join together manually in Python.

Comment: I don't believe anything in this answer (even prior to edit) is incorrect. Someone see something I need to update?